# Change color of first item in enumeration

Tags: color, enumerate

I encountered the following problem: I am using \textcolor to gray out parts of an enumeration. The enumeration symbols should appear gray as well, i.e. the \textcolor must enclose the \item. However, this always fails for the *first* item in an enumeration. It gives me a compilation error ("Something is wrong, maybe a missing item"). How can I fix this?
Here is a minimum example:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,parskip,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\gray}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}
\begin{enumerate}
%\gray{\item item 1}%fails with "missing item"
\item \gray{item 1} %works
\gray{\item item 2} %works, because it is the second item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\newcommand{\gray}[1]{{\color{gray}#1}}`, then it won't start a paragraph.

Comment: Hello Ulrike, thank you for your comment, that did the trick!

Comment: Actually, it does the trick too well. Now the problem is that all the following items are become gray as well...

Comment: No, be aware that I use two braces.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for your answers. As suggested by Ulrike Fischer, changing the command doing the coloring to

```
\newcommand{\gray}[1]{{\color{gray}#1}}
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/217216)

Comment: There was no answer to accept, as Ulrike provided the solution in a comment to the initial question. That is why I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple with `enumitem`, using the `before=` key:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,parskip,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[before=\color{lightgray}]
\item item 1
 \item item 2
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item item 1
 \item item 2
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Bernard, thanks for your reply! The issue with this solution is that I want to gray out only certain items, not all of them. Sometimes it happens to be the first one, sometimes not.

Comment: @rugermini: in this case a possible solution would consist in ending the `enumerate` environment and instantly reopen another one with options `[resume, nosep, before=·\color{lightgray}]` for those which have to be coloured, without `before=` for the others.